# DEVICE FARM , APPIUM , JAVA

Tags: appium, aws-device-farm

I have test cases written in JAVA and the project is not a TESTNG or JUnit.
I want to run my testcases on Device Farm.
I hav a jar file which has dependency on 3 properties file.

Answer (score 1):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Wrap you regular java classes test method calls inside TestNG calls. You can follow the sample example we host on github: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app .

   Once you have those wrapped then you can annotate the test methods using @Test and device farm will be able to pick those up.
2. The second way could be to try and see if you can run your Java test cases using a testNG runner. if that works locally it should work on device farm.

   A sample execution locally could look like:

   java -cp :/tmp/wd/*:/tmp/wd/dependency-jars/* org.testng.TestNG /tmp/wd/yourjavatestclasses-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar outfile

Of course both these methods above would need you to package your test cases as per our instructions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-testng.html